# Check which interval values lies within for each day, and create new matrix containing information of which interval in R

Tags: r, intervals, sapply

I am working with a dataset containing price information of over 700 cryptocurrencies from the period 2014-01-01 to 2019-12-31 called **price.daily**

```
            Bitcoin     Ethereum    XRP      Bitcoin.SV    Stellar    ...
   ...
2018-01-01  13657.20    772.64      2.39     NA            0.480008
2018-01-02  14982.10    884.44      2.48     NA            0.564766
2018-01-03  15201.00    962.72      3.11     NA            0.896227
   ...
```

I have then for each day calculated the quantiles using **sapply** as another question suggested, and this works just fine

```
col.daily <- seq(1,length(price.daily$Bitcoin))
quantile.daily = sapply(col.daily, function(y) {quantile(x = unlist(price.daily[y,] ), seq(0,1, length=6),na.rm = TRUE )})
quantile.daily.t = t(quantile.daily)
rownames(quantile.daily.t) = rownames(price.daily)
```

From which I get the number from where my intervals whould be

```
             0%         20%         40%         60%         80%     100%
   ...
2018-01-01   2.60e-05   0.1681120   0.7189722   2.3060000   9.392   13657.20
2018-01-02   3.40e-05   0.1946376   0.7232178   2.4240000   10.092  14982.10
2018-01-03   3.80e-05   0.1982452   0.7771724   2.4820000   10.054  15201.00
   ...
```

What I then want to do is for each day take the price of each cryptocurrency, and check which interval it lies within, and create a new matrix containing number 1 to 5 and NA if no data is available. Should come out as

```
            Bitcoin   Ethereum    XRP     Bitcoin.SV    Stellar   ...
   ...
2018-01-01  5         5           4       NA            2
2018-01-02  5         5           4       NA            2
2018-01-03  5         5           4       NA            3
   ...
```

I imagine I for this also could use **sapply**?

A sample of my data using `dput(head(price.daily))` for my price.daily data

```
structure(list(Bitcoin = c(771.4, 802.39, 818.72, 859.51, 933.53, 
953.29), Ethereum = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), XRP = c(0.026944, 0.028726, 0.027627, 0.028129, 
0.02523, 0.0257), Bitcoin.Cash = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), row.names = c("2014-01-01", 
"2014-01-02", "2014-01-03", "2014-01-04", "2014-01-05", "2014-01-06"
), class = "data.frame")
```

and for quantiles

```
structure(c(0.00044, 0.000353, 0.000303, 0.000301, 0.000271, 
0.00001, 0.0330034, 0.0319948, 0.0327684, 0.0318646, 0.0274614, 
0.0237276, 0.161692, 0.1793948, 0.163744, 0.1610448, 0.1579238, 
0.0728448, 3.014, 3.728, 3.85, 3.87, 3.814, 2.54200000000001, 
6.036, 7.578, 7.14, 7.434, 7.474, 7.188, 771.4, 802.39, 818.72, 
859.51, 933.53, 953.29), .Dim = c(6L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(c("2014-01-01", 
"2014-01-02", "2014-01-03", "2014-01-04", "2014-01-05", "2014-01-06"
), c("0%", "20%", "40%", "60%", "80%", "100%")))
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please provide a sample of you data to maximize your chances of getting help. I would recommend this [guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). `If possible try pasting the results dput(head(yourtable))` .

Comment: I added a sample, kept the four first coins, as there are over 700, that would be quite long. Hope i did that right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function [findInterval](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/findInterval) does exactly what you need. The only difficulty comes from applying it to the correct data.

Simple solution with a loop:

```
result_loop = price.daily
for (i in seq_len(nrow(price.daily))) {
  result_loop[i, ] = findInterval(price.daily[i, ], quantile.daily[i, ])
}
```

Alternative solution without a loop:

```
combined = cbind(price.daily, quantile.daily)
result_alternative = as.data.frame(t(apply(combined, 1, function(x) findInterval(x[1:ncol(price.daily)], x[(1 + ncol(price.daily)):ncol(combined)]))))
colnames(result_alternative) = colnames(price.daily)
```

The second solution (inspired by [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5626440)) has some additional problems like the memory overhead for the `combined` variable. Even if that weren't the case, I would still use the first solution. It can be tempting to use language constructs to avoid loops, but it makes debugging and maintenance much harder in many cases.

As a side note: The result can be a matrix instead of a data frame, but since `price.daily` is (unnecessarily) given as a data frame, I opted for using the same class for the result.